# Как тестировать апи с Laravel oauth

Tags: php, laravel, phpunit

Написал API на Laravel, аутентификация через laravel/passport. Как в тесте имитировать залогиненого пользователя? Не очень хочется вручную создавать в базе слиента, и отправлять запрос на апи чтоб получить токен

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Уже нашел ответ:

```
 private $user;

 protected function setUp()
 {
     parent::setUp(); // TODO: Change the autogenerated stub
     $this->user = new User(['name' => 'John', 'id' => 5]);
     Passport::actingAs($this->user, ['updateProfile']);
 }
```

И в нужном месте просто вызываем `$this->be($this->user);`